# Блок (div) со свойством ссылки.

Tags: jquery, javascript

> ```
> Есть таблица. Внутри ячейки (td) есть текст и блок (div),
> ```
>
> а внутри блока, есть ссылка. 
> Задача: при наведении не на ссылку, а на часть блока в котором находится ссылка, сделать так, чтобы это блок имел свойство ссылки, т.е. при нажатие на него можно было перейти на нужную станицу.

```
Сама таблица:
<table style="width: 535px;" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="one">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p><a href="zakazat.html"><span class="hh3"> Работа</span> <br /> Любой сложности... </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="two">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p><a href="zakazat-rabotu.html"><span class="hh3"> Курсовые </span> <br />Работа (теоретическая), Науч.проект (практика)... </a>
                    </div>
                </td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="che">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p><a href="zakazat-r.html"><span class="hh3"> Заказы</span> <br /> от 3 часов ...</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="pia">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p><a href="zakazat-p.html"><span class="hh3"> Перевод </span> <br /> другие...</a>
                    </div>
                </td>               
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: А что мешает вместо блока сделать ссылку поместив в нее необходимый текст

Answer (score 1):

```
Сама таблица:
<table style="width: 535px;" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="location.href='тут твоя ссылка';">
                    <div id="one">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p><a href="zakazat.html"><span class="hh3"> Работа</span> <br /> Любой сложности... </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="two">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p><a href="zakazat-rabotu.html"><span class="hh3"> Курсовые </span> <br />Работа (теоретическая), Науч.проект (практика)... </a>
                    </div>
                </td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="che">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p><a href="zakazat-r.html"><span class="hh3"> Заказы</span> <br /> от 3 часов ...</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="pia">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p><a href="zakazat-p.html"><span class="hh3"> Перевод </span> <br /> другие...</a>
                    </div>
                </td>               
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: а кто общим-то сделал?

Comment: Не понял вашего вопроса!